# MDB2 prepared statements and inserting NOW()

Tags: mysql, function, prepared-statement, mdb2

I'm working with MDB2's prepared statements and am a little confused with the [documentation](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.mdb2.intro-execute.php), specifically dealing with MySQL built-in functions like NOW() or CURDATE().

> The values passed in $data must be literals. Do not submit SQL
>   functions (for example CURDATE()). SQL functions that should be
>   performed at execution time need to be put in the prepared statement.
>   Similarly, identifiers (i.e. table names and column names) can not be
>   used because the names get validated during the prepare phase.

So the docs say to include these functions in the prepared statement, but I'm not sure how to account for the fieldnames.  For instance, if I have a table with five columns:

id 
lastname
firstname
gender
dateadded

And I want to insert a row with just first, last and dateadded...  I might use something like

```
INSERT INTO mytable (firstname,lastname,dateadded) VALUES('jane','doe',NOW())
```

If it weren't for the dateadded column I'd use something like:

```
    $types = array(
        'text', 
        'text' 
    );
    $sth = $mdb2->prepare('
        INSERT INTO 
            mytable 
        VALUES 
            (
                :firstname,
                :lastname
            )', $types);

    $data = array(
        'firstname'     => 'Jane', 
        'lastname'  => 'Doe'
    );
    $affectedRows = $sth->execute($data);
```

So -- how do I account for the MySQL function as far as listing out the fieldnames?  Or do I need to plan on inserting values for every field in the table?

Comment: yes it's better to post your another problem as a separate question as it has no connection with this one

Comment: thanks, posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189556/undefined-function-mdb2-driver-mysqliexecute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your problem.
Why not just add NOW() to the prepared statement, as it said?

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO mytable ( lastname, firstname, dateadded) 
        VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, NOW())';
$sth = $mdb2->prepare($sql, $types);
```

Comment: I wasn't sure I specify fieldnames with prepared statements - this is my first time using them.  Thanks for answering my newb question.